# Android TextView has height and width of 0

Tags: android

I have a small project where I want to reuse a certain UI component a few time so I created a widget by expanding a ViewGroup. In that ViewGroup I inflated a view that contained a TextView inside a LinearLayout and added that inflated view to the ViewGroup trough addView.

The outer LinearLayout expands itself perfectly but the inner TextView have getHeight() = 0 and getWith() = 0 when I view it through Hierarchy Viewer. The strange thing is that layout_height and layout_width is the values I gave them in my xml.

I don't have the code here but it looked something like this:

xml:

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

    <TextView  
        android:text="random text.."  
        android:layout_with="200px"  
        android:layout_height="50px" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
class MyWidget extends ViewGroup {
...

//In constructor  
myView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.xml, null);  
addView(myView);  

//In layout  
myView.layout(l, t, r, b);
```

I have tried to give my text view fill_parent values for size but it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried in Hierarchy Viewer to force a layout request? if it makes the textview show up, then you're probably facing a framework bug (that should be solved in API > 8 AFAIK).

Comment: No I didn't know I could do that. Will try when I get back later. I did however try a forceLayout() from within my widget a few times and that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you should create LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height) and set it to your TextView?

Comment: I guess, you have to call measure(...,...)

Comment: The TextView `layout_width` is missing a `d`. That probably doesn't help.

Comment: @thegrinner - That's probably just a typo in the posting; I think the project wouldn't build if that were in the actual source.

Comment: @Ted That's true, but I figured I'd at least point it out on the off chance that it had been suppressed and ignored somehow.

Answer (score 118):

> **Remember:`getHeight()` and `getWidth()`return `0` *if components are not drawn yet***.

---

**To find the width And height of a `View` *before it being drawn:***

1. First call `measure`

   ```
   view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
   ```
2. Now you can get width using `getMeasuredWidth` and height using `getMeasuredHeight`

   ```
   int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
   int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
   ```

---

I have posted some more ideas here: [**How to get width/height of a View**](http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html)

Comment: you have done it.  provided the one line answer to the most common question in all of #android

Comment: Gee I never saw this one at any answer regarding this issue.

Answer (score 4):

1) Here is some links to use Hierarchy Viewer on your dev phone.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html

and the class you'll need:

http://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer

2) You can also reuse layout like a component with the include tag:

```
<include android:id="@+id/your_id" layout="@layout/layout_name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I put a bounty on this one, and here is what I've found.

Inflating with a `null` reference is A Bad Idea(TM). Essentially, that View won't get the proper layout parameters it needs (its parent sets a whole bunch of them, with a whole bunch of magic/logic involved). So inflating into null means no parents, and no inherited layout parameters. One *can* manually set a number of these parameters, but due to the magic involved it might not solve your problem.

The "solution(s)" that I've come up with involve; using include (when you *know* how many you need) and pulling them into code, or inflating to a parent (when you need true dynamic, N things). And of course, the XML you inflate will have ID collisions, so I go about it by grabbing the last child (e.g. getChildAt(getChildCount()-1) ) of whatever I'm looking for, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing yourself as the root:

```
View.inflate(context, R.layout.xml, this);
```

Since you will be the parent of this View that complies with [the javadoc spec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

Comment: Be sure to remove the `addView(view)` line or you'll get a runtime exception for attempting to assign a view to another parent.