# When android calculate width and height of views

Tags: android, height, width

I create my hierarchy of views by code, and then I do `setContentView()`in the Activity with my root view like argument.

I need know width and height of one view in runtime but if i do `getWidth()` or `getHeight()`, i get 0. If i wait a few seconds i get the correct width or height.

I only want to know in what moment android calculate width / height of views. My code isn't outstanding

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074937/android-how-to-get-a-custom-views-height-and-width

Answer (score 3):

This is because in `onCreate()` the layouts haven't been calculated yet. So you need to add a `GlobalLayoutListener` to know when layouts has been calculated and placed in screen.

```
final View view = findViewById(R.id.root);
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
                    vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
```

Where root is the root layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout i.e). Assign your root layout with the @+id/root.

Comment: You were still typing as I posted :)

Comment: Haha yeah you posted the answer a couple of seconds before :P

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where you are trying to measure the view but my guess is it's in onCreate() or onResume()>

Try this in your onCreate().

```
// set a global layout listener which will be called when the layout pass is completed and the view is drawn
     mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
               // measure your views here
          }
     }
```

Here, mainLayout is a reference to the root view group of the layout.

This will also be called if the layout is resized after it's first drawn (views added in code, orientation changes etc) so you will always get the correct values.

Comment: Thanks for learning me something new. view.post doesn't seem to work on all devices. Another discussion on the same subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13944263/969325

Answer (score 1):

You can use some View class. add this :

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        super(w,h,oldw,oldh);
        if(oldw == 0 && w !=0){
         ...
        // w and h is what you want
    }
```

Comment: I put the `createScaledBitmap` method to there and it works perfect. Also the error that says `Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)` is disappeared. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, according to this [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)

> When an Activity receives focus, it will be requested to draw its
>   layout.

...and also measure view dimensions.

Focus receives after `onResume` and lose it after `onPause` method.